# LogFactory not printing to console

Tags: java

I used `LogFactory` as follows in my project:

```
Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(ContentFactory.class);
logger.info("-info-");
```

Why didn't it print on the console when I executed it?

Comment: Apache Commons logging? http://i.imgur.com/B6wXrl.png

Answer (score 0):

Can be for a number of reasons.

Are you using apache commons for logging?  Apache commons is only a wrapper, do you have an actual logging implementation like log4j?

Are you using Log4j?
If so;

- make sure you are using the correct log4j.properties file in the class path
- make sure you have a console appender
- make sure you have the logging level set to info or a log level that includes info messages (i.e. not warn, fatal, severe)

Comment: Yes, i using Log4j.
But logger.debug and logger.error can print to console just only logger.info can't.

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling us which `LogFactory` and `Logger` classes you are using.

Assuming that you are talking about Apache Commons Logging then:

- You are better of using a more modern logging facade; e.g. slf4j.
- The reason that stuff is not going to the console is most likely that you haven't configured the underlying correctly.

How do you configure logging?  Well it will depend on what underlying logger you are using.  Either way, there is a summary of what to do [in the javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/logging/commons-logging-1.0.2/docs/api/org/apache/commons/logging/package-summary.html).

Comment: I using 
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

Answer (score -1):

The [docs](http://commons.apache.org/logging/commons-logging-1.0.2/docs/api/org/apache/commons/logging/Log.html) for the Log class provide a method for determining if a certain logging level is enabled.

```
if(logger.isInfoEnabled())
    System.out.println("logging at the info level is currently enabled");
else
    System.out.println("logging at the info level is not enabled");
```